# QuickTheories: Way to create generator from a list

Tags: java, property-based-testing

Using the java library QuickTheories, is there a builtin way to create a generator from a list of values?

Something like:

```
public Gen<A> fromList(List<A> xs) {
    ....
}
```

Rolling your own is not too bad, but seems like reinventing the wheel:

```
List<TimeZone> timeZones = Arrays.stream(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()).map(id -> TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
return integers().allPositive().map(i -> timeZones.get(i % timeZones.size());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pick` seems exactly what you need.

From the javadoc:

`public <T> Gen<T> pick(java.util.List<T> ts)`

Generates a value by randomly picking one from the supplied. When shrinking, values earlier in the list will be considered "smaller".